# WCF : remote SQL Server 2005 database connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I'd like to know how to link my WCF application with a remote SQL Server database. By remote, I mean that is on the same network than me but not on the same computer/project.
I've the controll of the computer where the database is stored on.

What I've done so far : create my WCF application and try to add an ADO.NET connection. My issue : where to find the name of the server ? (and also : is it the good way to proceed ?).

Thanks !

Comment: The Server name is exactly same by which you connect your Management Studio and browse the databases.

Answer (score 2):

> where to find the name of the server?

Three options:

- whoever "owns" the database server *tells you* the details, and you put them in a configuration file (or some other configuration system)
- whoever "owns" the database server *tells some key user* the details, and the user puts them into a screen / api in the application
- something like the above, but you try to discover sql servers at runtime via [`SqlDataSourceEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx) (not a fan of this option, to be honest)

Answer (score 1):

Conntion string should look like

```
 Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

In Place of **myServerName** you can use IPAdress of machine

Comment: Let's say that my server IP address is 10.68.85.116 and the name of the server I found in the SQL Server manager is SXB20050\SQLEXPRESS. How to plus it to my application ?

Comment: @Derbie, if you found out `SXB20050\SQLEXPRESS` then just use it. `SXB20050` is machine name or server name and `SQLEXPRESS` is instance name.

Comment: Ok, i'm trying to us it but it's not working. In the ADO.NET window, I ask to create a new connection. Then is asked the name of the server, where I put SXB20050 but there is an error that explain that server is unreachable (not true : i'm remotely connected to it). Why so ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add `connectionString` in the `Web.config` file of the application

```
<add name="connectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=ServerName/PC-Name;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=userid;Password=pass"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Use the `connection string` in your code/Logic

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
```